azure-sdk-for-js is unable to unwrap a key which was wrapped using key-vault API separately
I have a random string 1a4cc8e6699527506... (96 characters) that I am considering as the original data key, planning to use it for encrypting data, let's call it orgDEK.
I used wrapKey API of Azure Key-vault to wrap orgDEK with some master key (say masterKey) and RSA1_5 algorithm and got 33dxW3pm1tsn... (342 characters), let's call it wrappedDEK.
Now, in my nodejs application, I have the following code snippet for unwrapping wrappedDEK, which is throwing Unable to decrypt specified value with this key. error.


const { CryptographyClient } = require('@azure/keyvault-keys');
    
const cryptographyClient = new CryptographyClient(masterKey, azureCredential, {
                serviceVersion: keyVaultApiVersion
            });
const unwrappedDEK = await cryptographyClient.unwrapKey(
                'RSA1_5', Buffer.from(wrappedDEK));



I followed unwrapKey documentation on Microsoft portal for the above usage.
Interestingly, if I use cryptographyClient.wrapKey to wrap orgDEK (say it gives wrappedDEKLib), the above unwrapping works.
In short, CryptographyClient from azure-sdk-for-js is not able to unwrap a key which was wrapped using Azure API.
Note: Buffer.from(wrappedDEK) gives a buffer of 342 bytes, however, wrappedDEKLib.result is a buffer of 256 bytes.

Did you resolve your issue?

@Rukmini, unfortunately no. :(
